# P2P Search Engine yacy: where is the source code?

Tags: java, search-engine, p2p

http://www.google.fr/search?q=yacy+OPENSOURCE
YaCy is free software (GPL-licensed) and open source.

but I can't seem to find where the source code is for download on http://yacy.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the source code is (also) in every downloadable release in the 'source' subdirectory...

Answer (score 3):

Here's their new GIT repo.
https://gitorious.org/yacy

Answer (score 1):

Read the first paragraph on http://yacy.net/Join.html

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the links?

https://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=3505&release_id=12962

Answer (score 1):

The YaCy serach engine server code is now available on their new GitHub project: https://github.com/yacy/yacy_search_server

The link to the source code can currently be found on their main webpage: http://yacy.net/en/index.html under the SOURCE CODE section of the top bar menu.  If the code moves again in the future I would expect the link on the YaCy project website to get updated.